# TTK Combobox does not style properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

I have been attempting to create a combobox that fits in with the rest of my UI; however the widget still looks like the default:
[image: A default ttk combobox]

In my attempts, I have tried to "brute-force" the widget into adapting to the color with the following code but to no avail:

```
self.root = tk.Tk() # Parent Container

# Other UI elements declared

self.themeSel_combo_theme.configure(
    "TCombobox",
    background=self.theme.get('bg'),
    foreground=self.theme.get('bg'),
    fieldbackground=self.theme.get('bg'),
    darkcolor=self.theme.get('bg'),
    lightcolor=self.theme.get('bg'),
    selectbackground=self.theme.get('bg'),
    selectforeground=self.theme.get('bg'),
    bordercolor=self.theme.get('bg'),
    insertcolor=self.theme.get('bg'),
    insertwidth=self.theme.get('bg'), # It uses a color, not a size value
    arrowcolor=self.theme.get('bg')
)

self.themeSel_combo = ttk.Combobox(self.quickTheme_cont, style="TCombobox")
```

The code above was made using [this website](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Changing+Widget+Colors) as a reference.

Note that `self.theme.get('bg')` returns  `#202020`

Comment: Are you sure the all those styles of combobox can be changed?

Comment: @CoolCloud, yes; as I said the reference I used said that all of those are valid options for ttk::combobox widgets

Comment: Maybe give a reproducible example so we can try it on.

Comment: Apologies for the inconvenience; after some research, I've found that using ```tk.Tk()``` somehow makes it so that ```ttk``` objects do not style properly; thus I had to change it to ```tk.Toplevel()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for the inconvenience; I've decided to keep this thread in case someone else needs help with this. It turns out that using the following command for creating the parent container makes it so that `ttk` objects do not style properly:

```py
self.root = tk.Tk()
```

Changing the aforementioned command to the following fixed the issue I was having:

```py
self.root = tk.Toplevel()
```